AWS ECS service deploys one task, then the rest
AWS ECS service is deploying slower than it should.
The desired count is 8, with minimum 100% maximum 200%.
It deploys 1 task. Then after that has successfully started, it deploys 7 more.
This increases the time to deploy.
Why? How can I have it to deploy 8 tasks at once?


